# CSS styling 'a' tag globally using Wordpress Theme

Tags: css

I am using the Wordpress Kale theme for my website and have so far been able to update the styles as necessary via the ‘Additional CSS’ section. However, whenever I attempt to make changes to the ‘a’ tag, none of these are implemented on my site. The only way I can get these working is to make changes to each style on each page, which is obviously not ideal as I add more and more blog posts. The way I have been doing it so far is listed below, however I need a way of implementing these changes globally, in the same way I have been doing with the h1, h2, h3, etc tags. As you will see, I am having to create new styles for each child section in the table I’m using to display the content. Any help would be great!

```
/* STYLING FOR POST FACEBOOK LINK */
#panel-560-1-1-0 > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(5) > td:nth-
child(2) > a {
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* STYLING FOR POST TWITTER LINK */
#panel-560-1-1-0 > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(6) > td:nth-
child(2) > a {
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
}

/* STYLING FOR POST INSTAGRAM LINK*/
#panel-560-1-1-0 > div > div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(7) > td:nth-
child(2) > a {
color: #545454;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps you need to do in order to edit those links:

1. First, make a child theme from the Kale theme:
   https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes
2. Then, add your css overrides for a {} and any other links to the style.css in the Kale Child Theme you've created. Best override I've created is this at the end of style.css:

   ```
   body a {color: red !important;}
   ```

If those child css overrides don't work you need to make them more specific; the code you reference in your example has more "specificity" so your overrides need to come after they are referenced (in css code order) and be more "specific" in the global css cascade.

If the css you've shown is in the child css then rather than override it simply edit them where you find them in the style.css sheet and that will override the Parent Theme styles.

This should fix your problem.

Comment: Initially, I created a child theme however this broke the navigation layout and so it would be preferable if I could just edit the code above as necessary. Is this possible?

Comment: I've just done a test and mine works fine. If yours doesn't them do the other suggestion I made which is to edit and update the style.css file. I just installed a fresh wordpress and made a Kale child theme and it's working fine.

Comment: I am using a plugin for creating the child theme which is probably why it broke the navigation. Did manage to find the appropriate selector from it though so all working now. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Glad to hear it! Vote up my answer if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help, I found the selector via a child theme editor (.single .entry-content a)

Comment: You should delete this and add it as a comment to the answer post.